# Present a Modal View When App Becomes Active

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to present a modal view controller (for a login screen) when my app launches, and also when it becomes active again after a user has hit the home button and then relaunched the app.

I first tried to present the modal view in the root view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method. That works great when the app first launches, but this method isn't called when the app becomes active again.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentModalView];
}

- (void)presentModalView {
    if(![AuthenticationService sharedInstance].isAuthenticated) {
        _modalVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:self.modalViewControllerIdentifier];
        _modalVC.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:_modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Next I tried to call this from my app delegate in the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    ModalPresentingUISplitViewController *splitViewController = (ModalPresentingUISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [splitViewController presentModalView];
}
```

This appears to work fine on the surface, but I get a `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ModalPresentingUISplitViewController: 0x7251590>` warning in my log. I get the sense that I'm somehow presenting the modal view before the UISplitView is finished presenting itself, but I don't know how to get around this.

How can I "automatically" present a modal view from my root view controller when the app becomes active, and do it at the "right" moment as not to unbalance my split view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot this question was here. Yes, I have a solution. I can't help but feel that there is a more elegant or *right* way to do this, but this worked for me...

This assumes you are using ARC and storyboards; You've created a UIViewController for your login view with a modal segue from the UISplitViewController (or whatever your root view controller is).

**UISplitViewController (or whatever your root view controller is)**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(presentModalView) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.viewHasAppeared = YES;
    [self presentModalView];
}

- (void) presentModalView {
    if(self.viewHasAppeared && !self.userAuthenticated) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLoginView" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowLoginView"]) {
        JDPLoginViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
        dest.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void) dismissLogin {
    self.userAuthenticated = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Here are the important parts of the code to note...**

1. We're calling `presentModalView` two places - in `viewDidAppear` which will take care of presenting our login view when the app first starts and
2. We are registering the `presentModalView` as an observer to the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification event so the method gets called when the app becomes active after being in the background.
3. Finally, we're creating a BOOL property `viewHasAppeared` on the UISplitViewController to keep track of whether the UISplitViewController's view has appeared or not so we don't try to present the modal login before the UISplitViewController's view has appeared.

**Here are the different scenarios...**

*App First Starts:*

- `presentModalView` is called by the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` event, but since the UISplitViewController's view isn't loaded (and the `viewHasAppeared` BOOL is NO, nothing happens. Win. We don't present the view when we shouldn't.
- Then eventually `viewDidAppear` is called, it sets `viewHasAppeared` to YES and then calls `presentModalView`. The login screen is presented. Everything works as expected - Yay!

*App Becomes Active After Being in Background*

- `presentModalView` is called by the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` event again as in the first scenario, but this time `viewHasAppeared` is YES, so login view is presented as expected. Yay again!

Like I said, this feels kind of ugly, but it gets the job done until I find a better solution. Hope it works for you.

Comment: What if other (perhaps multiple) view controllers have already been presented by the root view controller -- wouldn't the topmost active view controller be responsible for presenting to login vc?

Comment: Been quite a while since I've worked in iOS. In "normal" situations, your top-most VC would be responsible for presenting modals, but in the case of a login which may have to be presented at any point (even when other modally presented VCs are visible), I don't know that you have any other choice than presenting from the root.

Comment: I get the warning `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged` in the debug console when the root view controller presents the login view controller and the root view is not the topmost. I think you may need to burden each view controller with presenting the login view if necessary... If your root view controller is a tab bar controller (or split view like above) then its *always* on top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UIView's viewWillAppear?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` gets called before the view is even added to the view heirarchy (and before `viewDidAppear`), so that is definitely too early.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining off @jpolete's answer I did things a little differently. In addition I wanted the login screen to only appear after the app has been in the background for more the 15 seconds (it's painful for the user to *always* have to log back in).

The source code for this demo can be found on [github](https://github.com/wcochran/LockFoo)

Like @jpolete, I encapsulated most of the logic in the root view controller, which is a navigation controller in my case (iPhone example). The `userLoggedIn` flags whether or not the user has been authenticated. The `presentingLoginController` flag lets me know if the login screen is currently presented. `backgroundTime` holds a time stamp of when the user entered the background. Here is the class extension:

```
@interface RootNavigationController () <LoginDelegate>
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL userLoggedIn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *backgroundTime;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL presentingLoginController;
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*) notification;
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification*) notification;
@end
```

When the view is loaded I add the appropriate notification hooks:

```
@implementation RootNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Here we trigger the login segue if the user is *not* authenticated and we are not currently presenting the login controller.

```
-(void)loginIfNecessary {
    if (!self.userLoggedIn && !self.presentingLoginController) {
        self.presentingLoginController = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"RootLoginSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Here we set the root view controller to be the `loginDelegate` of the login controller.
This delegate is informed when a successful login occurs (the login controller is embedded in another nav controller):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"RootLoginSegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
        LoginTableViewController *loginController = (LoginTableViewController *) navController.topViewController;
        loginController.loginDelegate = self;
    }
}
```

When a successful login occurs we do the following:

```
-(void)didLogin { // LoginDelegate method called to login controller after successsful login
    self.presentingLoginController = NO;
    self.userLoggedIn = YES;
}
```

When the view appears for the first time, when it appears after being in the background, or after being "covered up" we login (if needed):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self loginIfNecessary];
}
```

When we enter the background we record the time:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification*) notification {
    self.backgroundTime = [NSDate date];
}
```

When we enter the foreground and its the first time or sufficient time has passed then we
force the user to log in again (if necessary):

```
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*) notification {
    const NSTimeInterval maxBackgroundTime = 15.0;
    if (!self.backgroundTime || [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.backgroundTime] > maxBackgroundTime) {
        self.userLoggedIn = NO;
    }
    [self loginIfNecessary];
}

@end
```